# TSQL DATEADD using ticks

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-function

### Context

In a table-valued function, the returned "table" is populated from a SELECT to this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [org].[work_schedule_time](
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [fk_schedule] [int] NOT NULL,
   [date_start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [date_end] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [is_repeating] [bit] NOT NULL,
   [repeat_interval] [bigint] NULL,
   [repeat_count] [int] NOT NULL,
   [is_available] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_work_schedule_time] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [id] ASC
)
```

The function takes three arguments :

1. the `@fkSchedule`
2. a `@dateMin` and
3. a `@dateMax` for the date boundaries

and return a table with the correctly populated date ranges. For example, for this row

```
id  fk_schedule  date_start               date_end                 is_repeating  repeat_interval  repeat_count  is_available
3   1            2013-06-03 08:00:00.000  2013-06-03 17:00:00.000  1             6048000000000    0             1
```

calling the function like this

```
SELECT * FROM [org].[work_schedule_time_fn](1, '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01')
```

Should return a table like

```
schedule_id  date_start               date_end
1            2013-06-03 08:00:00.000  2013-06-03 17:00:00.000
1            2013-06-10 08:00:00.000  2013-06-10 17:00:00.000
1            2013-06-17 08:00:00.000  2013-06-17 17:00:00.000
1            2013-06-24 08:00:00.000  2013-06-24 17:00:00.000
```

### Question

The column `repeat_interval` is a `bigint`, representing a C# `TimeSpan`. (There's already data in the table, and the application logic is already in use.)

I need to perform this call `DATEADD(ms, @repeatInterval / 1000, @dateStart)`, but I get a `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int`.

I have read several posts about it but some answers suggests subtracting `552877920000000000` or some other magic numbers, or some other voodoo matic tricks.

So, if I have a `bigint` value containing some ticks, that I need to add to a `datetime` column, what's the most correct way of doing this?

Thanks.

### Final solution

To avoid overflow again if the number of ticks is too great, I ended up adding minutes, then seconds, then milliseconds.

```
SET @dateStart = DATEADD(ms, (@repeatInterval % 10000000) / 10000, DATEADD(s, CAST(@repeatInterval / 10000000 as int) % 60, DATEADD(n, CAST(@repeatInterval / 600000000 as int), @dateStart)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `dateadd()` function takes an `int` argument, and the result of the division is too big for an int.

You can try this:

```
select dateadd(ms, (@repeatInterval%10000000)/10000 , DATEADD(s, cast(@repeatInterval / 10000000 as int), @dateStart))
```

That is, first add the "seconds", then add the milliseconds.

If the number of seconds is still too big, you can move to larger and larger time frames.

Comment: excellent! Thanks. I think I've read this solution in some forum, but somehow it did get to me. (note that I corrected the values to convert ticks per seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the @repeatInterval / 1000 I believe the outcome of this will be float (from memory)

I got it to work using this, casting the result of the division back to a bigint. You might want to look at rounding it first as the result of a plain cast can lead to inaccuracies.

```
declare @dateStart dateTime
declare @repeatInterval bigint

set @dateStart = GetDate()
set @repeatInterval = 30000

select @dateStart, DATEADD(millisecond, cast((@repeatInterval / 1000) as bigint), @dateStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer, while perfectly valid and usable in most circumstances, loses both potential precision and scale. The scale is truncated to milliseconds even though ticks are accurate to 100ns and the expression will still overflow when a timespan of more than 68 years is presented. Both can be avoided by switching from milliseconds to nanoseconds and adding a third dateadd level for days. I know it is overkill, but the following expression works for pretty much any duration that can be expressed with sql server datatypes.

```
Declare @sec bigint = 10000000;
Declare
    -- Our starting point in time.
    @Moment datetimeoffset = N'1000-01-01 00:00:00.0000000+02:00'

    -- Several durations stored as ticks
,   @TicksSmall bigint = 1234567
,   @TicksMedium bigint =
        (12 * @sec * 60) + (34 * @sec)
    +   1234567
,   @TicksBig bigint =
        (DateDiff( Day, N'1000-01-01', N'1000-12-12' ) * @sec * 60 * 60 * 24)
    +   (12 * @sec * 60 * 60) + (34 * @sec * 60) + (56 * @sec)
    +   1234567
,   @TicksHuge bigint =
        (DateDiff( Day, N'1000-01-01', N'9999-12-12' ) * @sec * 60 * 60 * 24)
    +   (12 * @sec * 60 * 60) + (34 * @sec * 60) + (56 * @sec)
    +   1234567
;

Select
    @TicksSmall As Ticks
,   DateAdd( nanosecond, Convert( int, (@TicksSmall % 10000000) * 100 )
    ,   DateAdd( second, Convert( int, (@TicksSmall % 864000000000) / 10000000 )
        ,   DateAdd( day, Convert( int, @TicksSmall / 864000000000 ), @Moment )
        )
    ) As Moment
Union all
Select
    @TicksMedium
,   DateAdd( nanosecond, Convert( int, (@TicksMedium % 10000000) * 100 )
    ,   DateAdd( second, Convert( int, (@TicksMedium % 864000000000) / 10000000 )
        ,   DateAdd( day, Convert( int, @TicksMedium / 864000000000 ), @Moment )
        )
    )
Union all
Select
    @TicksBig
,   DateAdd( nanosecond, Convert( int, (@TicksBig % 10000000) * 100 )
    ,   DateAdd( second, Convert( int, (@TicksBig % 864000000000) / 10000000 )
        ,   DateAdd( day, Convert( int, @TicksBig / 864000000000 ), @Moment )
        )
    )
Union all
Select
    @TicksHuge
,   DateAdd( nanosecond, Convert( int, (@TicksHuge % 10000000) * 100 )
    ,   DateAdd( second, Convert( int, (@TicksHuge % 864000000000) / 10000000 )
        ,   DateAdd( day, Convert( int, @TicksHuge / 864000000000 ), @Moment )
        )
    )
;
```